# Reading all kind of extesion using Java for Encryption/Decryption purpose

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

I am develpoing a program that would allow to load file with any extension and encrypt it using some algortihm.

I am done with the Encryption part, and I am using java `File` class to load files.

But the problem is, I cannot be able to load PDF file using `File` object.

Here is my code to load a file,

```
 /** 
     * Read bytes from a File into a byte[].
     * 
     * @param file The File to read.
     * @return A byte[] containing the contents of the File.
     * @throws IOException Thrown if the File is too long to read or couldn't be
     * read fully.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static byte[] readBytesFromFile(File file) throws IOException {
      InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

      // Get the size of the file
      long length = file.length();

      // You cannot create an array using a long type.
      // It needs to be an int type.
      // Before converting to an int type, check
      // to ensure that file is not larger than Integer.MAX_VALUE.
      if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        throw new IOException("Could not completely read file " + file.getName() + " as it is too long (" + length + " bytes, max supported " + Integer.MAX_VALUE + ")");
      }

      // Create the byte array to hold the data
      byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)length];

      // Read in the bytes
      int offset = 0;
      int numRead = 0;
      while (offset < bytes.length && (numRead=is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length-offset)) >= 0) {
          offset += numRead;
      }

      // Ensure all the bytes have been read in
      if (offset < bytes.length) {
          throw new IOException("Could not completely read file " + file.getName());
      }

      // Close the input stream and return bytes
      is.close();
      return bytes;
  }
```

and this is how I am loading a file in Hex,

```
File file = new File("F:/filepath.pdf");

        System.out.print(BaseEncoding.base16().encode(LoadFile.readBytesFromFile(file)));
```

When I load the text file and Print it i get the hex output and when I convert that Hex output into ASCII characters, I get the actual data of the text file, but this is not happening in case of `PDF` file.

It merits mentioning here that I have nothing to do with the data after loading it, all I need to do is encrypt it, and when I decrypt it, I should be able to get the actual data back. 
And this is happening correctly only for text files but not any other extension, like apk, pdf, doc etc.

I have seen an app in Play Store that is capable of taking input any file and then encrypt it using AES-256 and saves it and then when we decrypt it, we get the original file.

Can any one provide me with any clue on how to encrypt all sort of files regardless of their extension ?

Here is the test code that I used to first load the pdf file as bytes and then save it as an another pdf file.

```
public static void writeBytesToFile(File theFile, byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
      BufferedOutputStream bos = null;

    try {
      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(theFile);
      bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos); 
    }finally {
      if(bos != null) {
        try  {
          //flush and close the BufferedOutputStream
          bos.flush();
          bos.close();
        } catch(Exception e){}
      }
    }
    }
```

Writing,

```
File inputfile = new File("F:/perfect-secrecy.pdf");
        File outputfile = new File("F:/p.pdf");


    LoadFile.writeBytesToFile(output, LoadFile.readBytesFromFile(inputfile));
```

The genrated output file here is 0kb and I dont know why.

Comment: You're not writing anything to `bos`. Not to mention that empty catch blocks are great way to never know what's going wrong.

Comment: You can read/write to binary (or bytes/octets really). Hexadecimals is a method of *representing* binary data, it isn't the value of the hexadecimal data. So you don't read / write to hex normally, that's just how the bytes are diplayed.